How to avoid audio distortion while combining 2 channels into 1
I've got a Mac .net application, and all it needs to do is record audio and then write it into a WAV file.
I'm using a C# wrapper for PortAudio to record the audio. I've managed to record and write a WAV file for one-channel audio successfully and, the same for two-channel. But when I try to record two-channel audio and then write it as 1 channel audio, it becomes distorted. The combination of 2 channels to 1 is done by taking interleaved pairs of samples, adding them together, and then dividing by 2. With steps taken to try and avoid overflowing.
And yet when combining the channels, the end result becomes distorted. I'm convinced it's something basic and easy that I'm doing horrifically wrong but I can no longer spot it.
The code for recording:

        private static readonly int _sampleRate = 44100; 
        private static int _totalSamplesWritten = 0;
        private const ushort BIT_DEPTH = 16 ;

        var param = new StreamParameters
        {
            device = _indexOfDevice,
            channelCount = device.maxInputChannels > 1 ? 2 : 1,
            sampleFormat = SampleFormat.Int16,
            suggestedLatency = device.defaultLowInputLatency,
            hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = IntPtr.Zero
        };

        StreamCallbackResult CallbackStereoInput(
            IntPtr input, 
            IntPtr output, 
            uint frameCount, 
            ref StreamCallbackTimeInfo timeInfo, 
            StreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, 
            IntPtr userData
        )
        {
            var samples = new short[frameCount];
            Marshal.Copy(input, samples, 0, (int)frameCount);
            
            for (var i = 0; i < frameCount; i++)
            {
                var sampleL = samples[i];
                var overflowSafeSampleL = Convert.ToInt32(sampleL);
                var sampleR = samples[i + 1];
                var overflowSafeSampleR = Convert.ToInt32(sampleR);
                
                var combinedSample = overflowSafeSampleL + overflowSafeSampleR;
                var dividedSample = Convert.ToInt16(combinedSample / 2);
                
                _outputFileWriter.Write(dividedSample);
                i++;
            }
            
            _totalSamplesWritten += (int)frameCount;

            return StreamCallbackResult.Continue;
        }

        _stream = new PortAudioSharp.Stream(
            inParams: param, outParams: null, 
            sampleRate: _sampleRate,
            framesPerBuffer: 256,
            streamFlags: StreamFlags.ClipOff,
            callback: param.channelCount > 1 ? CallbackStereoInput : CallbackMonoInput,
            userData: IntPtr.Zero
        );

Code for Writing WAV header:
WriteWavHeader(_outputFileWriter, 1, BIT_DEPTH, _sampleRate / 2, _totalSamplesWritten);

private static void WriteWavHeader(BinaryWriter writer, ushort channelCount, ushort bitDepth, int sampleRate, int totalSampleCount)
    {
        writer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        writer.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("RIFF"));
        writer.Write((bitDepth / 8 * totalSampleCount) + 36);
        writer.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("WAVE"));
        writer.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("fmt "));
        writer.Write(16);
        writer.Write((ushort)1);
        writer.Write(channelCount);
        writer.Write(sampleRate);
        writer.Write(sampleRate * channelCount * bitDepth / 8);
        writer.Write((ushort)(channelCount * bitDepth / 8));
        writer.Write(bitDepth);
        writer.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("data"));
        writer.Write(bitDepth / 8 * totalSampleCount);
    }

I don't care too much about loss of audio quality as long as you can clearly and easily understand human speech from it.
An example of the distorted audio:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/5204zxtpjkqa4ewxhph0j/Audio.wav?rlkey=9urdo4s0zqtyd3hxi1oscko9b&st=w02xj8pm&dl=0
The code above is the end point after multiple different attempts.

Currently, the sample rate we write to the WAV is half the rate which we record at, but without that change, the audio length gets halved and played back at double the speed.
The Sample rate used to be 16000, and that seemed to produce slightly better results but from everything I've read online it seems like 44100 is a better bet.
Initially, it was just static when I combined the channels, but casting the samples to32 bit while combining them seems to help avoid overflow.
I've tried different sampleFormats, and I've tried non-interleaved audio but it does not seem to make anything any better or worse.
It definitely can work nicely as recording 2 channel audio and writing it as 2 channel audio works nicely, so I'm fairly confident it's not a hardware issue.
The main reason why I'm trying to combine 2 channels of audio into 1 is that I need the final WAV file to be as small as possible. I need fine audio quality and where I can save space is a bonus, and getting 2 channels into 1 would be a massive file size slasher.


Are you sure that the WAV raw data is in a signed int16_t and not an unsigned uint16_t? That would have the effect of flipping half the waveform upside down...

@MartinBrown Confirmed, doesn't seem like I'm converting to unsigned at any point, looks to be signed at the point of writing to the WAV file.

I think you will find that PCM coding is usually done from 0 to 2^N-1 monotonically increasing in voltage (most hardware DACs & ADCs use this convention). IOW you possibly should be using uint32_t and uint16_t for the arithmetic see for example Wiki PCM coding.

Managed to figure it out in the end. The samples from PortAudio are interleaved into 1 sample. So one sample contains left and right, I was combining left and right pairs with other left and right pairs.
I needed to split the individual samples from the 'samples' array into two, in order to get the left and right audio streams. Once I got that figured out, I could actually average them into 1 stream by adding them together and dividing by 2 into a single signed int16.
